# Salary Calculator Source?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator

Is the source code available for the salary calculator anywhere?

I'd love to see the full equations instead of trying to reverse engineer the numbers.

Comment: I think they've mentioned somewhere that the salary calculator is modeled after the self-description of devs during the survey.

Comment: Do you mean [our "How We Pay" calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator), or are you referring to [the calculator on the Job Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary)? The former tells you how much you'd earn if you worked here; the latter is a general estimate of market value based on self-reported salaries in our annual developer survey

Comment: Either would be helpful, but I was specifically referring to the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no open source that we could find. We wrote a quick scraper to get the numbers and try and reverse engineer the equation (for developers only):

https://gist.github.com/timup/a019caac1c3f42af99f9165757c4183a

which is non-linear:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqZrVv

In general, we believe a salary is based on the previous level salary, and includes a 4.4% bump for each skill level and a 1.4% - 1% bump for each year of experience.

Hope this helps someone else looking at the same information.

Comment: I doubt SO will appreciate you reverse engineering their product and posting the results on their platform of all places...

Comment: Trying to reverse engineer one of their products is a bold plan, lets see if they appreciate it.

Comment: A bold plan indeed, made me chuckle. 10/10